# Run script each minute

Tags: php, html, session

I want to run a script each minute after the start button is pressed.

How can i achieve this?

This is the code i want too run:

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loggedUser = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `availableTime` FROM `user` WHERE userName='$loggedUser'");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$time=$row['availableTime'];

if ($time > 0){
mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `availableTime` =  `availableTime` - 1 WHERE userName='$loggedUser' ");
} else {
mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `availableTime` =  `availableTime` = 0 WHERE userName='$loggedUser' ");
    header( 'Location: http://192.168.42.1/kick.php?ip=' . $_SESSION['ip'] ) ;
}
```

Comment: you should use cronjob

Answer (score 4):

If you're on unix use [crontab](http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial), if you're on windows use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

Cron Example (every minute)

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/html/yourscript.php
```

---

**Change of heart**

I think what you want to do here is use AJAX in the users browser to call this script every minute and check if the user is still allowed to be logged in, if the user shouldn't be logged in, you should kill their session with PHP and then redirect them with javascript.

Comment: I am on unix, would crontab work when multiple users are signed in?

Comment: Crontab would just run that script as often as you set it to. In this case you need to change your queries to search for ANY users who's time has expired.

Answer (score 1):

Use crontab/windows task scheduler and execute it via php by exec() / system()

Answer (score 0):

Following your question. **after the start button is pressed**. 
you need using javascript/jquery to do it.

you can use below function to call the your script with AJAX  within 5000 milisecond

```
setInterval(function(){ajaxcall();},5000);
```

Below was the function ajax call

```
function ajaxcall() {
  AJAX call your php script
}
```

Comment: This looks like what i want! How could i wrap this code in a button?

Comment: you can do like this,
add onclick event on the button to call the it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call your php script from a javascript call

```
 var timerID = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      context: document.body
    });
  }, 60 * 1000);


  clearInterval(timerID);
```